# jquery ajax call returns php file contents

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery ajax function which queries a php file (carousel.php) and does some stuff with the result. This all works fine on our development server, but on our live server the script seems to fail and returns the content of the PHP file (the raw code). So the PHP isn't even executed. What could be the case here?

```
        $.ajax({
        url: 'carousel.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            if(result.success){
                if (result.numRows == 0) {
                    $('#insert').css('display','none');
                }
                $('#selectBox').html(result.html);
            } 
        }
    })
```

Comment: When you run the file within the broswer, does it execute or it return raw code ?

Comment: Hmmm... It presents me with the options to open or download the file.

Comment: Ok so the solution I see is map the .php extension to the PHP file type or check the extension .. is it php3 or something ?

Comment: Also, try to create a PHP file with an error in it and try to open it in your browser. Also try a different broswer / PC.

Comment: http://www.tutorialdash.com/tutorial/website-development/web-servers/view/Custom-File-Extensions-using-htaccess_85321

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed (i can see it on source code of page)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)

Comment: Thanks David and PeeHaa for your tips. I can't quite wrap my finger around it at this time. It's not some basic mistake ;) To get my desired result I took it all the way around and created something completely different.

Answer (score 3):

You probably use `<?` tag in your php file and short open tag is not enabled on your server.

Comment: Do people still use it? If that really is the case OP deserves it, but I doubt it (at least I hope not :0 ).

Comment: I don't know, that's why I wrote "probably" :)

Comment: Thanks, good hint (I'm aware). Nope don't use short open tag here.